# Xcode 4 Real-time collaborative editing

Tags: macos, xcode4

I really love the look and feel of the new xcode (4). But, a friend and I wanted to see if there is any way we can do collaborative real-time editing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor). Just like what you see when you use Google Docs to edit a word document with someone.

Also, could/is there (be) a plug in that should work with xcode for Real-time collaborative editing? Or anything of the like?

Thanks for the post back,
Throdne

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you? If so, please accept it, if not, please provide further information.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this and since Xcode doesn't really support plugins, there is no way of live collaboration in Xcode. I would suggest to use [Sub Etha Edit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/). As an editor for Objective C, it's obviously not as great as Xcode, but still, it does a pretty decent job and might serve you well in your setup.

Comment: Xcode does not support this. There aren't any rumors of it coming either. Apple may surprise us but for now SubEthaEdit is your best bet ... you just don't get the benefit of Xcode's completion and analysis.